# vba ppt to choose language to display the presentation (not to translate it)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to create a ppt presentation in which you can choose the language of the text to be shown from various texts previously written (i.e. English, Spanish,..) Is it possible with VBA?

Comment: Certainly it's possible.  Will people here write it for you?  Certainly not.  But they'll be very generous in helping you write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll try, of course

Comment: If I were doing this, I'd store the individual bits of text for each shape as tags on the shape. For example, a shape on slide 1 might contain "Hello" in English to begin with but is also tagged e.g.  Shape.Tags.Add "English", "Hello" and also Shape.Tags.Add "French", "Bonjour" and so on. Then when you want to switch to French, your code can look at each shape with text, read the value in Shape.Tags("French") and change the text of the shape to that.  Read up on tags here if you like: http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00815_Working_with_Tags_-and_a_bit_about_Functions-.htm

Comment: Thanks again Steve